# Screen big data without interrupting data conversion

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, buffer, gnu-screen, tee

This thread is an extension of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31027735/54964) where the interruption (CTRL-c) stop the data transfer into less. 
I would like to create a similar system monitoring data conversion as is found in `fdupes`. 
I think this can be reached with GNU `screen`. 
The tools `tee` and `buffers` may not be needed for this so skip the two sections if you want.

### Hex conversion and tee [skip if you know]

You can use whatever hex dumper you want for the task, for instance `hexdump -v`, `od -v -t x1` and `xxd -ps` for the generation of the example data. 
You can create binary test data 1GB by the following command, discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193166/15504)

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.bin bs=64M count=16
```

Let's simplify the old situation without the while loop. 
Assume you have a very big file. 
You put it as STIN into less by

```
hexdump -v sample.bin | less -s -M +Gg
```

I am discussing [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193159/15504) how to generate you big test files. 
With a big file, you get an empty screen when you do not press anything, since conversion under way. 
When you press `CTRL-c`, you get the data that has been already converted to the less at the bottom of the screen. 
This is not all data. 
Does the interruption by `CTRL-c` end the transfer of data from file into less?

Possibilities to fix this

- refresh the less somehow if the conversion is still underway
- bind `tee` command here somehow

Is there any way to avoid the interruption of the data conversion but be able to look the stream. 
I think `tee` command could be one possibility.

### Buffers [I think not needed]

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 xxd -ps sample.bin | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 less -s -M +G
```

which does not resolve the problem. 
I should be able refresh the output in less, where I am using the flag `R`. 
Only interruption will show something in `less`.

I did not manage to get `unbuffer` command work similarly as `stdbuf`, discussing it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212364/16920).

### Screen

I think the best way to have a glimpse of the data conversion is to run everything inside `screen`. 
Logic: give stdout into `less` inside `screen`. 
Scroll the output in `screen`. 
I have completed such a task before which may be found in my thread about `screen`. 
I have to think this once more again. 
I would like to create a similar usability as in the command `fdupes`. 
I think `tee` and `buffer` may not even be needed.

How can you create screen about monitoring window when less is viewing parallerly data conversion?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691884/zenity-progress-from-handbrake-cli-output/14124550?s=1|1.0482#14124550 (`unbuffer` and `stdbuf`) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I added an attempt about buffers which however does not solve the problem. Another problem may be in refreshing the output in less. I can only disrupt less which shows then the output but I would like see updates which the user can update in less.